Customize Payload in Webhook Subscription - HubSpot
I have created a Private App in HubSpot which is sending requests to an external URL using a Webhook, but by any chance do you know if it is possible to customize a payload from a subscription? the default payload only includes these values:
{ "appId": 123123, "eventId": 100, "subscriptionId": 32132, "portalId": 321321, "occurredAt": 123123123, "subscriptionType": "deal.propertyChange", "attemptNumber": 0, "objectId": 123, "changeSource": "CRM", "propertyName": "abc", "propertyValue": "value" }
However I would like to send extra fields information on the payload. For example:
{ "appId": 123123, "eventId": 100, "subscriptionId": 32132, "portalId": 321321, "occurredAt": 123123123, "subscriptionType": "deal.propertyChange", "attemptNumber": 0, "objectId": 123, "changeSource": "CRM", "propertyName": "abc", "propertyValue": "value", "extraField": "value of my extra field", ...Any other field I need }
I was looking around the HubSpot console but I haven't found an option to customize this payload, also reviewed the docs but I wasn't able to find related information.
